# Unable to update the host.json file in azurefunctions

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

Am working on azure functions trying to set `"maxConcurrentCalls":1` using `host.json`.

I updated these settings in `wwwrootfolder` of `FunctionApp` as well and updated in local hosted environment. But these changes are not getting applied to the functions while running.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug that max concurrent calls doesn't work properly in Azure functions version 2.0